# How to disable flutter initialization progress indicator?

Tags: flutter, web, loader

Is it possible to disable upper line progress indicator when Flutter loads web entry point?
The thing is, it is blue and does not fit my app color theme.

Comment: The indicator is only displayed when you are in debug mode, a release build won't have it.

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't appear in release mode, just try this:

```
(optional) flutter create . (it's to create the web folder if you don't have it)
flutter build web
flutter run -d chrome --release
```